# Chrome: white rounded borders glitch

Tags: google-chrome, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4ZNM/1/)

```
.rounded{
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 10px
}

.rounded:hover{
    border-color: #333;
}
```

At first glance you may not see the issue. But on certain monitors and under certain angles there is a slight glitch on rounded corners. Though they are white on white background, they are not invisible. Here is the original screenshot and photoshopped one:

[image: original][image: darkened]

Is there a way to get rid of the ghostly border?

Comment: where? and why a blank-code link to jsfiddle?

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: correced the link and added the question

Comment: Chrome bugs can be reported at https://crbug.com

Answer (score 0):

It’s **not a glitch** but it’s not the thing you expected it to be. This is it. You can’t do anything about it. **But it’s not a GLITCH.**